# onEdit specific cell copy data from one google sheets to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, triggers

In google sheets, I am trying to get one data to copy from one sheet to another.

I have this code which is working however I would like it to run onEdit when changing cell E4 in Googlesheet1. I am new at this and doesn't seem to get it to quite work with the solutions I found online.

```
function ExportRange() {
  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('googlesheet1');
  var destinationSheet = destination.getActiveSheet();      
  var destinationCell = destinationSheet.getRange("AC3");
  var cellData = '=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/googlesheet2", "AE10:AE9697")';
  destinationCell.setValue(cellData);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Chose between a [simple](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) and [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) `onEdit` trigger, depending on your requirements
- For most applciaitons a simple `onEdit` trigger is sufficient, to use it you just need to rename your function `ExportRange()` to `onEdit()`
- Take advantage of [event objetcs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) that give you informaiton about the event that fired the trigger
- So, the trigger `onEdit` can give you among others information about the `event range` - that is the range that has been edited
- Now you can implement an `if` statement to specify that the rest of the funciton shall only be run if the `event range` and the corresponding sheet are as required

**Sample:**

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var range = event.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if(range.getA1Notation() == "E4" && sheet.getName() == "Googlesheet1"){
    var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('googlesheet1');
    var destinationSheet = destination.getActiveSheet();      
    var destinationCell = destinationSheet.getRange("AC3");
    var cellData = '=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/googlesheet2", "AE10:AE9697")';
    destinationCell.setValue(cellData);
  }
}
```

> Please note that this function can only be fired by the trigger in
>   case of an edit. If you try to run it manually, it will give you an
>   error because `event` (and thus `event.range`) will be undefined if
>   the funciton was not called by an edit event.